# C# Screen Capture in Parallel?

Tags: c#, screenshot

I'd like to capture a screenshot of an application's window. I can do this using the below. However, is it possible to do this in parrall or does it have to happen sequentially?

I am currently making use of [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/):

```
ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture(); // capture entire screen, and save it to a file 
Image img = sc.CaptureScreen(); // display image in a Picture control named imageDisplay 
this.imageDisplay.Image = img;  // capture this window, and save it 
sc.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle,"C:\\temp2.gif",ImageFormat.Gif);
```

**Is there any way I can take screen-shots in parallel for two or more application windows?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used that library before but from your code example it seems you are not capturing a specific window but your entire screen.

it seems you want to use the function

```
public void CaptureWindowToFile(IntPtr handle, string filename, ImageFormat format)
```

and pass it the handle of the window of the application you want to capture. It seems you can use that on as many windows as you want with the library it is just a matter of getting the handle of the correct window.

Comment: To be honest, I am not looking for ways to use the above class but to understand if its possible to capture an image of a window at the same time doing it for another window i.e. in parrallel?

Comment: Then the answer to your question is yes. The code in the library could actually all be made static as there is nothing being done in the constructor and there is no variables not scoped locally to the function.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look into "threads":

- http://www.albahari.com/threading/
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Basically, you should launch concurrent threads to handle a specific work, eg giving the window handle as a parameter for the thread job.

Comment: Yes, I understand the use of threads but what I am trying to work out is if the process of the screen capture will limit a thread to only capture a window/screen at a time.